# How to filter out numbers in an array PHP

Tags: php, math

I don't know why I can't get my head around this problem. Probably because I should be getting rest, but I have to at least solve this first.

- Lets say that I let people rent my bicycles.
- I have 4 of them.
- Each of them are numbered 1, 2, 3 & 4.
- Today no. 1 & 3 was already rented(which is saved in the database)
- The third customer arrives and I wanted to see the "available"
  numbers, which are supposed to be 2 & 4.

  $bicycles = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
  $rent = array(1,3); 
  $available = array();

How to save the available numbers in $available and at the same time count the number of available bicycles?

The problem actually has more factors involved, but I'll be okay if I get to settle this first. Hopefully.

Comment: Use a database instead of an array? (Yet you say there is already a database, so I don't get it, why aren't you using it?)

Comment: `$available=array_diff($bycycles,$rent);` will quickly give you what is in $bicycles and not in $rent.

Comment: @developerwjk It is because I want the ones that are not available. The bicycles numbers are not in the database, this is just a simpler form. There are hundreds of groups of bicycles, so I had to deal with them by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array_diff is a better way to go, but this is easier to follow.

```
// Your bikes
$Bikes = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

// Rented bikes
$Rented = array(2, 3);

// Create a result array that we will fill as we loop
$Available = array();

// Find the difference manually by looping
foreach($Bikes as $Bike){

    // If the bike isn't rented, add it to the Available array
    if(!in_array($Bike, $Rented)) array_push($Available, $Bike);

}

var_dump($Available); // should contain 1 and 4
```

Comment: I suspected there were functions for it, but couldn't find any related to it. Thanks for helping out a junior in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to return the difference between two arrays, and count() or sizeof() to return the number of elements in an array.

Comment: This actually makes me curious on how PHP handles this. But I guess that is another question. Thanks.

Comment: There is a problem using this function though, the array key started from 2, 3, ... I wonder why that happened since in the documentation it shows that it starts from 1.